Почему возникает ошибка (TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue')?
Хотел сделать бота для WordPress, который будет выкладывать посты, которые я буду писать ему в Telegram чате.
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
import requests

# Настройки
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'bot token'
WP_URL = 'https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
WP_USER = 'user'
WP_PASSWORD = 'pass'

# Аутентификация WordPress
def get_wp_token():
    response = requests.post(
        f'{WP_URL}/jwt-auth/v1/token',
        data={'username': WP_USER, 'password': WP_PASSWORD}
    )
    return response.json().get('token')
    введите сюда код

# Обработка сообщений
def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    text = update.message.text

    # Аутентификация`введите сюда код`
    token = get_wp_token()
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}

    # Отправка поста
    response = requests.post(WP_URL, headers=headers, json={
        'title': 'Новость из Telegram',
        'content': text,
        'status': 'publish',
        'categories': [7]  # Укажи ID категории новостей
    })

    if response.status_code == 201:
        update.message.reply_text('Новость опубликована!')
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Ошибка публикации.')

# Настройка бота
def main():
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Но выдает такие ошибки:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\news_bot\bot.py", line 64, in <module>
main()
~~~~^^
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\news_bot\bot.py", line 54, in main
updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'


Отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: 'update_queue'️‍♂️

Возможно данные вопросы помогут исправить ошибку:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363018/how-to-resolve-typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-up
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064123/unable-to-run-python-telegram-bot-package-error

